# Swift can a switch case statement have multiple arguments?

Tags: swift, enums, switch-statement

If I have set my cases in enum, can I call multiple of those cases in a switch statement? aka `case .a, .b: return true`

```
enum myLetters {
  case a
  case b
  case c

    var myCondition: Bool {
      switch self {
      case .a, .b: return true
      case .c: return false
      default: return false
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Your code compiles and runs fine (although the `default` case is redundant) – what exactly is your question?

Comment: why is the default redundant? doesnt myLetters need a default case?

Comment: It's redundant because your enum only has three possible values. Since the `switch` statement covers those three values, the use of `default` is pointless. It will never be reached.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes, take a look at Swift's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ControlFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH9-ID139) on `switch` statement.

In order to achieve what you want, you need to check for the current value of `myLetters`:

```
var myCondition: Bool {
    switch self {
    case .a, .b: return true
    case .c: return false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want to group cases with the same **assosiated value**, you can do the following:

```
var myCondition: Bool {
  switch self {
  case .a(let value), .b(let value): return value
  case .c(let value1, let value2): // do stuff with value1 and value 2
  }
}
```

Unfortunately you can't currently combine the `let` statements to a single one.

Comment: Thanks so much @danielhadar ... was just looking for how to switch through cases using these values and the let keyword saved my life. Thanks again bud!